# Play 2.1 - Session with SimpleResult (Scala)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have a problem with the session in play.

I have a controller with this method:

```
def index = Action {
  implicit request =>
    Ok(html.index("Dashboard")).withSession(request.session.+ (Defines.SESSION_MENU, "1"))
}
```

My question is why in first rendering of the page I don't have the new element in the session and what I have to do to get this behaviour?

Thanks,
Diego

Comment: I experienced the exact situation and got it solved using `Redirect` instead of `Ok`. Try this: `Redirect(routes.Application.index("Dashboard")).withSession(request.session.+ (Defines.SESSION_MENU, "1"))`. This may be not a proper solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: isn't that a recursive call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.withSession` adds element(s) to the session cookie, which are only transmitted in headers. So, when the template is rendered the first time, they are not in the session. On further renders, it should work fine.

It looks like you'd like to use the session in your template. In which case, the best strategy would likely be to explicitly pass in the session parameters that you want to use, including the new one(s).